# pymongo cannot connect to database on remote server

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have setup a mongodb server running on an external host server, I can connect the mongo client easily by doing the following in the client computers shell:

```
162.243.27.34 --port 27017
```

but when I try to connect to the server using pymongo using python I get the following output

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient('162.243.27.34', 27017)
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 352, in __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: could not connect to 162.243.27.34:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong here?

## update - some more info

The database server in on the IP 162.243.27.34 and the client is a separate server with a different IP. In the above examples in both cases I'm attempting to connect from a remote client server rather than connecting to 'localhost'.

There is a firewall on the database server but the client does have access and as the mongo client command line program connects fine from the client server I'm assuming that there is no network problem in connecting from the client to the database server, rather that there is a problem in how I'm using python to connect.

## update 2

running the command:

```
cat /etc/mongodb.conf
```

shows:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
#port = 27017
```

Also I'm using MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4

Comment: Were you connecting from the shell locally or remotely. So was the shell connection on the same server instance that `mongod` is running on? If so, did you then use the same IP address or the localhost (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the reply, I added some details to the question

Comment: Okay so to be clear. You are using the **same** IP address to connect from the **same** client that you are trying to run your python app from. Is that correct? Also try `ps aux | grep mongod` on the mongo server and/or look for `bind_ip` in the configuration file that is used. Make sure it is not different to the one you are posting or is otherwise `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Correct I am connecting from the same IP using python and the 'mongo' command line client. Here's the output of the comamnd you sent me run on the database server, `mongodb   1184  0.4  3.1 639596 15936 ?        Ssl  Mar18   5:47 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
jon       3148  0.0  0.1   9392   888 pts/0    S+   06:51   0:00 grep mongod` I don't see any bind ip, have I done something wrong?

Comment: Use `cat /etc/mongodb.conf` and edit your question with the bind_ip value found or if it's not there do not bother. Also the version shown when you connect from the shell.

Comment: So can you **see** your problem now. You can **only** connect to this from the localhost despite the content in the comments here. Change that to `0.0.0.0` and restart the mongod service. Your problem will go away.

Comment: I can see that that is a problem, but it still seems odd to me that I can connect with the mongo shell from the remote computer when the python connection doesn't work from from the same same remote computer

Answer (score 6):

Replace the `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` with `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` to allow connections to MongoDB from remote hosts.

Comment: 2023 This is still valid

Answer (score 0):

1. go to /etc/mongo.conf
2. find all entries with bind_ip (depending where you run your db server you might have more than one entry)
3. make sure you only have one live entry with bind_ip
4. replace the 0.0.0.0 with two entries: 127.0.0.1,internal ip,external ip - if you want to connect from outside the cloud installation
5. save and exit
6. restart Mongo with *sudo service mongod restart*
7. Add a firewall rule to allow traffic from your app server

Note: if you have more than one node, you might need to handle identifying in your app server code which node is primary and set the connection to it. This means that you would need to do the above for each data node. Alternatively, set one data node with priority = 1 and all the rest with priority = 0 (using Mongo shell). For example:

```
cfg = rs.config()
cfg.members[<node id>].priority = 0
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

I am using MongoDB with Google Cloud (one click deployment with 2 nodes + arbiter) and it is running fine