# Remote Mongo Connection via Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am connecting to a remote server's port 27017 using ssh and then accessing the mongo database on that system. I can successfully connect it via the shell script. However, when I write a python program and try to connect to that system, I am not able to connect. I use the following piece of code:

```
conn = MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@hostname:27017/database')
```

I would want to mention that I am accessing the destination system behind a proxy. However, the port 27017 is enabled for my system to connect to the destination system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pymongo cannot connect to database on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501838/pymongo-cannot-connect-to-database-on-remote-server)

Answer (score 2):

```
conn = MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@hostname:27017/database')
```

Your hostname is `27017` but the port you enabled is `27107`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I am enabling the correct ports. Edited the question.

Comment: In that case it may be something to do with your IDE. In my pycharm I have to set up a server to the localhost:27017 and then connect via the plugin. What are you using?

Comment: I am using plain sublime text. I can connect to local mongo systems without any issue. The problem is when accessing a remote server.

Comment: @AyushiDalmia Were you able to solve this problem? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Here the same. please provide a soloution.